# AngularJS 1.x: filter bug(?) on null columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with multiple filter fileds (one for each column).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="search.name"></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="search.phone"></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="search.secret"></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="search.nullcol"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search:strict">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{user.secret}}</td>
        <td>{{user.nullcol}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everything works fine except filtering on a column containing null values: when I type something in the filtering field, all rows with null disappear (correctly), but deleting the filter does NOT restore them.

Here's a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/viMHsxBHI4CjfjWqWjti

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: I may have found a solution: I put a watch on the filter fields and when empty I remove the property from the search object.

Here's the updated plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7wE58QBUAqPHe8CGb4Bj

Nevertheless, I'd like to know if a more elegant solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because after entering text and deleting it, `search.nullcol` evaluates to an empty string rather than null.

Here is one solution: You could apply `ng-change` to the `nullcol` input to check if it's an empty string. If so, set it to `undefined`. Honestly, I don't know if this would be best practice, but it does work. I was surprised I couldn't find other solutions for this quirk.

```
<th><input type="text" ng-model="search.nullcol"  ng-change="checkIfEmpty()"></th>
```

Add to JS:

```
$scope.checkIfEmpty= function(){ 
   if ($scope.search.nullcol === '') {
      $scope.search.nullcol = undefined;
   } 
};
```

This will 'reset' the filter if that input is empty.https://plnkr.co/edit/Uv5DdQ70kGRYZQEwXgrn?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Your solution is similar to mine, didn't see it before posting my comment above. I still don't fully understand what's going on: I appreciate that "empty string" can be considered different from a null value but then again the same is true for non-null values. I still believe a proper fix is needed in this case.